# not able to connect to mongodb and mongo express in docker compose

Tags: mongodb, docker

I have the following docker compose file

```
services:
  mongodb:
    container_name: mongodb
    image: mongo:6.0.5-jammy
    volumes:
     - ./data:/data/db
    ports: 
     - "27017:27017"
    networks:
      mongonet:
       ipv4_address: 172.20.0.10
    environment:
     MONGODB_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root 
     MONGODB_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password#123
     MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: storage

  mongoexpress:
    depends_on: 
      - mongodb
    image: mongo-express:1.0.0-alpha.4
    ports:
      - "8080:8081"
    networks:
      mongonet:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.11   
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_AUTH_DATABASE=storage
      - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME=admin
      - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD=password#123
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=172.20.0.10
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=root
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password#123
  
networks:
  mongonet:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.20.0.0/24
          gateway: 172.20.0.1
```

but I get the following error:

```
environment-mongoexpress-1  | Welcome to mongo-express
environment-mongoexpress-1  | ------------------------
environment-mongoexpress-1  | 
environment-mongoexpress-1  | 
environment-mongoexpress-1  | (node:7) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: Current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
mongodb                     | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-09T15:46:47.866+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"172.20.0.11:59230","uuid":"22a9901c-23d5-4ede-ab6e-7885e3d10889","connectionId":1,"connectionCount":1}}
mongodb                     | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-09T15:46:47.878+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn1","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"172.20.0.11:59230","client":"conn1","doc":{"driver":{"name":"nodejs","version":"3.7.3"},"os":{"type":"Linux","name":"linux","architecture":"x64","version":"5.15.0-70-generic"},"platform":"'Node.js v12.22.7, LE (legacy)"}}}
mongodb                     | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-09T15:46:47.879+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":20251,   "ctx":"conn1","msg":"Supported SASL mechanisms requested for unknown user","attr":{"user":{"user":"root","db":"storage"}}}
mongodb                     | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-09T15:46:47.880+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":20249,   "ctx":"conn1","msg":"Authentication failed","attr":{"mechanism":"SCRAM-SHA-256","speculative":true,"principalName":"root","authenticationDatabase":"storage","remote":"172.20.0.11:59230","extraInfo":{},"error":"UserNotFound: Could not find user \"root\" for db \"storage\""}}
mongodb                     | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-09T15:46:47.886+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":20249,   "ctx":"conn1","msg":"Authentication failed","attr":{"mechanism":"SCRAM-SHA-1","speculative":false,"principalName":"root","authenticationDatabase":"storage","remote":"172.20.0.11:59230","extraInfo":{},"error":"UserNotFound: Could not find user \"root\" for db \"storage\""}}
environment-mongoexpress-1  | Could not connect to database using connectionString: mongodb://root:password#123@172.20.0.10:27017/storage"
environment-mongoexpress-1  | (node:7) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [172.20.0.10:27017] on first connect [MongoError: Authentication failed.
environment-mongoexpress-1  |     at Connection.messageHandler (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:364:19)
environment-mongoexpress-1  |     at Connection.emit (events.js:314:20)
environment-mongoexpress-1  |     at processMessage (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:456:10)
environment-mongoexpress-1  |     at Socket.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:625:15)
environment-mongoexpress-1  |     at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
environment-mongoexpress-1  |     at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:297:12)
environment-mongoexpress-1  |     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:272:9)
environment-mongoexpress-1  |     at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:213:10)
environment-mongoexpress-1  |     at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23) {
environment-mongoexpress-1  |   ok: 0,
environment-mongoexpress-1  |   code: 18,
environment-mongoexpress-1  |   codeName: 'AuthenticationFailed'
environment-mongoexpress-1  | }]
environment-mongoexpress-1  |     at Pool.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/server.js:441:11)
environment-mongoexpress-1  |     at Pool.emit (events.js:314:20)
environment-mongoexpress-1  |     at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:564:14
environment-mongoexpress-1  |     at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:1000:11
environment-mongoexpress-1  |     at callback (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:75:5)
environment-mongoexpress-1  |     at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:158:27
environment-mongoexpress-1  |     at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/auth/scram.js:110:14
environment-mongoexpress-1  |     at _callback (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:333:7)
environment-mongoexpress-1  |     at Connection.messageHandler (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:364:9)
environment-mongoexpress-1  |     at Connection.emit (events.js:314:20)
environment-mongoexpress-1  |     at processMessage (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:456:10)
environment-mongoexpress-1  |     at Socket.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:625:15)
environment-mongoexpress-1  |     at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
environment-mongoexpress-1  |     at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:297:12)
environment-mongoexpress-1  |     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:272:9)
environment-mongoexpress-1  |     at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:213:10)
environment-mongoexpress-1  | (node:7) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
mongodb                     | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-09T15:46:47.899+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn1","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"172.20.0.11:59230","uuid":"22a9901c-23d5-4ede-ab6e-7885e3d10889","connectionId":1,"connectionCount":0}}
environment-mongoexpress-1  | (node:7) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
mongodb                     | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-09T15:46:48.034+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":20631,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Unclean full-time diagnostic data capture shutdown detected, found interim file, some metrics may have been lost","attr":{"error":{"code":0,"codeName":"OK"}}}
environment-mongoexpress-1 exited with code 0
```

Comment: This isn't your problem, but why are you using static ip addresses? You should use hostnames instead; then you don't need to worry about ips.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is:

```
UserNotFound: Could not find user "root" for db "storage"
```

I see several issue in your `docker-compose.yaml` that might cause this. First, you have misspelled some environment variables.  These:

```
MONGODB_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root 
MONGODB_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password#123
```

Should use the `MONGO_` prefix rather than `MONGODB_` (just like your `MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE` variable):

```
    environment:
     MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
     MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password#123
     MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: storage
```

Setting `MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE` won't actually create the `storage` database. From the docs for the mongo image (*emphasis mine*):

> `MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE`
>
> This variable allows you to specify the name of a database to be used for creation scripts in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*.js`. MongoDB is fundamentally designed for "create on first use", so if you do not insert data with your JavaScript files, **then no database is created.**

Next, users are created in the "admin" database:

> `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME, MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD`
>
> These variables, used in conjunction, create a new user and set that user's password. **This user is created in the admin authentication database** and given the role of root, which is a "superuser" role.

This means you need to modify your `mongo-express` environment variables:

```
environment:
  - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME=admin
  - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD=password#123
  - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_AUTH_DATABASE=admin
  - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb
  - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=root
  - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password#123
```

Finally, odds are that the mongo express container will start up and attempt to connect to mongo *before* mongo is available to service requests. Setting `depends_on` in your configuration is effectively a no-op. It's more effective to configure mongo express to restart automatically by adding:

```
restart: always
```

Or to create a healthcheck on the mongodb container:

```
healthcheck:
  interval: 10s
  timeout: 10s
  retries: 3
  start_period: 10s
  test:
    - CMD
    - sh
    - -c
    - |
      mongosh \
        -u "$$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME" \
        -p "$$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD" \
        admin --eval 'db.stats()'
```

And configure mongo express to wait for the mongo container to become healthy:

```
mongoexpress:
  depends_on:
    mongodb:
      condition: service_healthy
```

---

A complete, functional `docker-compose.yaml` looks like this:

```
services:
  mongodb:
    container_name: mongodb
    image: mongo:6.0.5-jammy
    volumes:
     - mongo_data:/data/db
    ports: 
     - "27017:27017"
    environment:
     MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
     MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password#123
     MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: storage
    # Note the use of `$$` instead of `$` in this
    # script to prevent `docker-compose` from trying
    # to expand the variables.
    healthcheck:
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 10s
      test:
        - CMD
        - sh
        - -c
        - |
          mongosh \
            -u "$$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME" \
            -p "$$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD" \
            admin --eval 'db.stats()'

  mongoexpress:
    depends_on:
      mongodb:
        condition: service_healthy
    image: mongo-express:1.0.0-alpha.4
    ports:
      - "8080:8081"
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME=admin
      - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD=password#123
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_AUTH_DATABASE=admin
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=root
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password#123

volumes:
  mongo_data:
```